# What does "Beniek was part of that band of kids, one of the bolder ones." mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, swimming-in-the-dark, tomasz-jedrowski

I would like to know what "Beniek was part of that band of kids, one of the bolder ones." means in the following sentences:

> It was on the wide pavements, lined with trees and benches, that all the children of the neighbourhood played together. We would play catch and skip ropes with the girls, and run around the courtyards, screaming, jumping on to the double bars that looked like rugby posts and on which the women would hang and beat their carpets. We’d get told off by adults and run away. We were dusty children. We’d race through the streets in summer in our shorts and knee-high socks and suspenders, and in flimsy wool coats when the ground was covered in leaves in autumn, and we’d continue running after frost invaded the ground and the air scratched our lungs and our breath turned to clouds before our eyes. In spring, on Śmigus-Dyngus day, we’d throw bucketloads of water over any girl who wasn’t quick enough to escape, and then we’d chase and soak each other, returning home drenched to the bone. On Sundays, we’d throw pebbles at the milk bottles standing on the windowsills higher up where no one could steal them, and we’d run away in genuine fear when a bottle broke and the milk ran slowly down the building, white streams trickling down the sooty facade like tears.
>
> **Beniek was part of that band of kids, one of the bolder ones.** I don’t
> think we ever talked back then, but I was aware of him. He was taller
> than most of us, and somehow darker, with long eyelashes and a
> rebellious stare. And he was kind. Once, when we were running from an
> adult after some mischief now long forgotten, I stumbled and fell on
> to the sharp gravel. The others overtook me, dust gathering, and I
> tried to stand. My knee was bleeding.

- [Tomasz Jedrowski, *Swimming in the Dark*, Chapter 1](https://www.booker6.com/book/202006/842_2.html)

In this novel which is set in the 1980's in Poland under the socialist regime, where homosexuality was socially unacceptable, the protagonist Ludwik (a university graduate) left Poland in 1981 to live in the United States of America. And he remembers what it was like back then in Poland, where he used to hang out with his friends including his first love Beniek in his hometown of Wrocław when he was nine years old.

In this part, I wonder whether the sentence means that Beniek belonged to the group of kids, and also to the selected small group composed of bolder kids among them, or that Beniek belonged to the group of kids who were generally bolder. In short, I would like to know whether "that band of kids" is the same concept with "the bolder ones," or is a larger concept incorporating "the bolder ones."

I am an English learner from South Korea. I would very much appreciate your help. :)

Comment: I'm curious why this question got a downvote? It seems perfectly legitimate. Perhaps more suited to ELL than to Lit SE, but has enough literature content to qualify for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*That band of kids* refers to all the children who did the things Ludwik is remembering: playing catch, running about, throwing water on the girls on Dyngus Day, throwing pebbles at milk bottles. Within that band of kids, some are more bold than others. Beniek is *one of the bolder ones*. That is, he would probably try things with less fear than most of the other children in the group. So if Ludwik, for example, breaks a milk bottle for the thrill, but feels *genuine fear* after doing so, Beniek would probably feel more of the thrill and less of the fear. Also, being bold as well as kind, he will help Ludwik when Ludwik trips and falls while all the children are running away from an angry adult, instead of continuing to run off and leaving Ludwik to face the angry adult by himself.

Comment: If I understand correctly, what confused the OP is the juxtaposition of "part of that band of kids" and "one of the bolder ones" with a comma between. Is there a name for this type of comma usage? I think it's not exactly a comma splice? Adding something about this sentence form, as well as the meaning of the phrases, might help the OP too.

Comment: Thanks. Corrected; it should indeed be Beniek. I don't know how to explain the syntax of the sentence OP is asking about, sadly.